# Div height driving me mad

Tags: css, html, height

i have a layout based on divs like this:

```
<div id="master">
 <div id="header">Header</div>
 <div id="menu">Menu</div>
 <div id="content">Content</div>
 <div id="footer">Footer</div>
</div>`
```

All vertical aligned.

HTML, body height is 100%
same goes for master div.
when i set content div to 100% it expands and gives me scroll bar.

My goal is to get content div to fill out the rest. putting footer to bottom and header & menu on top.

I cannot seem to achieve this.

any help?

Comment: Have you set the margins to zero?

Comment: Hey check http://jsfiddle.net/Cj8YV/1/

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is your `body`'s `margin` or `padding`. Try resetting them:

```css
#master {padding-top: 0; padding-bottom: 0; overflow: auto;}
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Cj8YV/1/

Comment: THey are html, body {
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;

Comment: @user2759588 Can you please show us the full code and it would be good if you can make a fiddle.

Comment: @user2759588 You have padding top and bottom for the `#master`. Remove that and you are good to go. And also, to control, give `overflow: hidden;`. See my updated answer. :)

Comment: Im affraid not, you can try yourself in fiddle.Ah update ok ^^

Comment: It makes a scrollbar within the div now :S im lost. going back to <tables> soon

Comment: @user2759588 Yes, because the content is more than the height. If you don't want a scrollbar, you may use `overflow: hidden;`

Comment: My content isnt high, i want #indhold to fill the screen. When i set overflow:hidden; it just hiddes boxcontainer and footer

Answer (score 0):

You'll find many helpful answers if you search for "push footer down", for instance this: [How do you get the footer to stay at the bottom of a Web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42294/how-do-you-get-the-footer-to-stay-at-the-bottom-of-a-web-page)

If your footer height is fixed, try restructuring the HTML code like so:

### HTML

```
<html>
<head>...</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
header, content and menu goes here
<div class="push"></div>
</div>
<div class="footer">footer</div>
</body>
</html>
```

### CSS

Include the following CSS (I copied the code from the linked answer and put in some background colors, so it can be tested easily):

```
* {
    margin: 0;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -142px; /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's height */
    background: red; /* demo */
}
.footer, .push {
    height: 142px; /* .push must be the same height as .footer */
}
.footer {
    background: blue; /* demo */
}
```